# Prism Container Resolve Thread Safe

Tags: thread-safety, singleton, prism

Is it thread safe if i want to create an instance of some type via Prism container resolve method that was previously registered as singleton? Unfortunately i couldn't find any info on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by thread-safe, and depending on the answer to that, what implementation of ServiceLocator you are using.

Both MEF and Unity containers are thread-safe in the sense that Resolve can be called independently from multiple threads for the same type.  Theoretically you could have some other kind of ServiceLocator which was not thread-safe in this respect, but I would be surprised to find one, because it would make thread synchronization across a Prism app a real chore.

What may not be thread-safe is the actual object that is returned from the container.  For instance, if you registered a Dictionary object and asked for that back, there is nothing magical about ServiceLocator that would make the Dictionary's operations thread safe.